# can not delete file with root in /etc/pam.d directory

Tags: centos7

can not delete file in /etc/pam.d directory with root user on centos7.7 system,please help work out this problem.

```
#rm -f /etc/pam.d/2.txt
rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/pam.d/2.txt’: Permission denied
```

directory and file permission as follow:

```
$ ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4096 Aug  3 19:29 /
$ ls -ld /etc
drwxr-xr-x 154 root root 12288 Aug  3 22:26 /etc
$ ls -ld /etc/pam.d/
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Aug  3 22:26 /etc/pam.d/
$ ls -l /etc/pam.d/2.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug  3 19:37 /etc/pam.d/2.txt
```

But when i rename pam.d to pam.dd(mv pam.d pam.dd) ,it is can delete file under pam.dd,it's strange! selinux is not open,selinux content also removed,facl is not set

```
# ls -lZd /etc
drwxr-xr-x root root ?                                /etc
# ls -lZd /etc/pam.d
drwxrwxrwx root root ?                                /etc/pam.d
# ls -lZd /etc/pam.d/2.txt
-rwxrwxrwx root root ?                                /etc/pam.d/2.txt
```

both file and directory is mutable

```
# lsattr -d /etc/pam.d
---------------- /etc/pam.d

# lsattr /etc/pam.d/2.txt
---------------- /etc/pam.d/2.txt
```

Comment: Might have better luck with this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: think you for commit